# How do I represent these complements in membership tables?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I couldn't find examples of some of these elsewhere, so I'm just kind of guessing here. I'm fairly certain I've made a mistake somewhere, particularly the columns with complements. I've placed asterisks beside the ones I think might be wrong. Could anyone take a look? Thanks!

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c} 
 \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & {A \cup\overline B} & {A \cap B} & {\overline {B\cap C}} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0* & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1* & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @almagest could column 4 be a subset of the union of columns 5 and 6 then? (Wolfram Alpha says it is so I thought I'm wrong somewhere.) I'm not sure if that requires the truth values to be exactly the same. The union of columns 5 and 6 have the same truth table except the first asterisk is a 0 instead of a 1.

Comment: Col 4 is A or not B, so it is true for the bottom four rows (where A is true) and also in the top two where B is false. Col 5 is both A and B, so is only true in the bottom two rows. The last col is quite different. It has nothing to do with A. it is true unless both B and C are true.